# A convex optimization problem in non-familiar format

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a convex optimization problem of the following form subject to some affine constraints:
$$\min_p c_1(a^tp)^{-1}+c_2 (b^tp) + c_3 (d^tp)^2$$
$$\text{s.t. some affine constraints}$$

where $c_i$ is a constant scalar. I know that for the feasible set, the objective is convex, but I cannot transfer it into a known category, like GP, QOQC, ...

I tried to map it to a geometric programming, but I reached to a $\frac{\text{posynomial}}{\text{posynomial}}$, which I couldn't continue furthermore. Any idea?

Comment: I think you must assume $a^tp >0$ for all relevant choices of the $p$ vector, and constants satisfy $c_1>0$, $c_3 >0$.  You can define two new scalar variables $z$ and $x$ and minimize $c_1 z^{-1} + c_2b^tp + c_3x^2$ subject to the existing constraints and two new linear constraints $z=a^tp$ and $x=d^tp$.  So now everything is separable.

Comment: @Michael Actually for my problem, $c_1$ and $c_3$ are positive, but $c_2$ is negative. In addition, for my problem $a=b$

Comment: That does not impact my comment above.

Comment: @Michael, Yes professor Neely, I said that my problem quite satisfy your assumptions. Thanks a lot for your precious help. I will attack the problem from your point of view

Comment: If you were using a tool like [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx) (disclosure: my package), you'd be able to express the objective as `minimize(c1*inv_pos(a'*p)+c2*(b'*p)+c3*square(d'*p))`; and assuming that the constraints were convex and could be expressed according to CVX's rules, you'd be in business. CVX would convert this particular problem to a second-order cone program (SOCP), so one could in theory do that manually, too.